# How to find sub node in node by using sax parser

Tags: java, android

```
package adapters;

public class XMLParser extends DefaultHandler{
    String question_id = "";
    String question_text = "";
    OptionsParser option_parser3 = new OptionsParser();
    OptionsParser option_parser1 = new OptionsParser();
    OptionsParser option_parser2 = new OptionsParser();
    List<OptionsParser> option_list = null;
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        option_list = new ArrayList<OptionsParser>();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a = 22;
        if(localName == "question"){

            question_id = attributes.getValue("id");
            question_text = attributes.getValue("text");
        }

        if(localName == "optoins"){
            option_parser1.setOption_id(attributes.getValue("id"));
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("option")){ 
            option_parser1.setOption_text(qName);
        }
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("option")){
            option_parser1.getOption_text();
        }



    }


}
```

question is node and option is subnode plz tell me how to find subnode (options) in questions.
please tell me for loop in sax parser.
as soon as possible

question is node and option is subnode plz tell me how to find subnode (options) in questions.
please tell me for loop in sax parser.
as soon as possible

Comment: Can you please show the url and xml which you need to parse?

Comment: see the link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/